# First order logic - each vertex of graph lies on some cycle

Tags: logic, graph-theory

We consider only undirected graphs.
I would like to show that there exists sentence $\phi$  in FOL such that $G\models \phi$  if only and only each vertex of $G$ lies on some cycle.

Problem for me is that this graph ma be infinite.  When it comes to finite case it is easy to give $\phi$:  $$\forall_{u
\in V}\deg(u)\ge 2$$, what may be expressed in FOL.  It is easy to show that  every vertex (in finite graph) lies on some cycle only and only each vertex of the graph has degree at least $2$.

However, I can't deal with infinite graph. In particularity, $\phi$ must be true both finite and infinite graphs. Of course if in infinite graph each vertex lies on some cycle then we can say that each vertex has degree at least $2$.

I can't prove that If in infinite graph each vertex has degree at least $2$ t then each vertex lies on some cycle.

Can you help me ?

Comment: What do you mean with "only and only if" (2nd line) and "only and only" (by the middle)? Is it "if and only if"? And wouldn't graph-theory be a better tag? I suppose it would be very adequate...

Comment: Yes, it means "if only and only" - I edited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't true, by a compactness argument.

Suppose that $\varphi$ be a sentence of first-order logic such that for every finite graph $G,$ $G\models\varphi$ iff every vertex of $G$ lies on some cycle.  We'll show that this can't be true also for every infinite graph.

Expand your language by adding a new constant symbol $c,$ and consider the theory $T=\lbrace \varphi \rbrace \cup \lbrace "\!c\text{ does not lie on a cycle of length exactly }n\!" \mid 0\lt n\lt \omega\rbrace.$

Then every finite subset of $T$ is satisfiable (by, for example, a finite graph consisting of one large cycle of length longer than any of the lengths mentioned in the particular finite subset of $T).$

Therefore $T$ is satisfiable.  But any model of $T$ is a graph which satisfies $\varphi$ but in which the interpretation of the constant symbol $c$ lies on no cycle.

Comment: I am not sure If I correctly understand you. Did you show that such sentence in FOL can't exists, yeah?

Comment: That is correct. You can rephrase this as a proof by contradiction. Assume that $\varphi$ has the property you want, and then use that argument to construct an infinite graph which satisfies $\varphi$ but which has an element that doesn't lie on any cycle. One thing that you need to be careful about is that, for each $n,$ the statement $"\!c\text{ does not lie on a cycle of length exactly }n\!"$ can be written as a sentence of first-order logic, but that's straightforward.

Comment: To be honestly I don't understand your solution. What is $\omega$ ? What is $c$ ? any node ? Where are you using compactness theorem ? To show that $T$ is satisfable ? How to express in FOL that $c$ doesn't lie on cycle of exactly length $n$ ? How you construct this infinite graph ?

Comment: @HaskellFun $\omega$ is the set of natural numbers.  $c$ is a new constant added to the language (it will turn out to be interpreted as a node not in a cycle in the proper model). Yes, I'm using the compactness theorem to say that $T$ is satisfiable because every finite subset of $T$ is satisfiable. You can express "$x$ doesn't lie on a cycle of length $n$" by simply writing down what it means: "there do not exist nodes $y_1, y_2, \dots, y_n$ such that ...." The infinite graph is simply any model of $T$ (which we proved is satisfiable).

Comment: $\omega = \mathbb{N}$ ? Or, maybe you mean: $T=\{\phi\}\cup \{...|0<n<1\}\cup \{...|0<n<2\}\cup \{...|0<n<3\}\cup ....$. Ok, you managed to prove that $T$ is satisfable (it was sufficient to show that there exists such finite graph that it satisfy finite susbet of $T$). So, from compactness theorem we know that $T$ is satisfable - all right. However, I can't understand last thing: where and how did you conclude contradiction ?

Comment: In other words: If I correctly understand $T$ and first of all I don't understand how you get contradiction.

Comment: $ $1. Assume for all $G, G\models\phi$ iff every node in $G$ lies on some cycle. 2. For each $n,$ let $\psi_n(x)$ be the formula $"{x}$ does not lie on a cycle of length $n."$ 3. Add a new constant $c$ to the language; set $T=\{\phi,\psi_1(c),\psi_2(c),\psi_3(c),\dots\}.$ 4. $T$ is finitely satisfiable: for any finite $S\subseteq T,$ here's a model of $S:$ a graph consisting of one cycle of length > largest $n$ such that $\psi_n\in S;$ interpret $c$ as you wish. 5. $T$ is satisfiable by compactness so it has a model $G.$ 6. $G\models\phi,$ but the interpretation of $c$ in $G$ lies on no cycle.

Comment: It is better and better. The last point 6. is incomprehensible for me. Try to not use word *interpretation* please. I think that in 6. you mean that: because of $G$ should fulfill $\psi_i(c)$ condtion for each $i$ so there exists such node (here c) that it doesn't lie one cycle. Contrary, $T$ can't be satisfable.

Comment: You can't avoid thinking about interpretations: a constant symbol is just a symbol, but in any specific model, that symbol will be used to mean some particular member of the model; that particular member is the *interpretation* of the symbol. So $c$ is just a constant symbol, not a node itself. In the model $G,$ the interpretation of $c$ is some actual node in $G.$ This node can't lie on a cycle, since any cycle has some length $n,$ but $G\models\psi_n(c).$ The contradiction is that $G$ also satisfies $\phi,$ and we've assumed that that implies that every node in $G$ lies on some cycle.

Comment: $G\models\psi_n(c).$ - we know it from compactness theorem. ($n$ is any natural number). Hence, there exists some node in this graph that doesn't lie on a cycle. Contradiction. Yeah ?

Answer (score 0):

[This isn't a second answer — it's an extended, too-long comment in reply to a comment on my earlier answer.] For every $n, G\models\psi_n(c)$ because: (1) each $\psi_n(c)$ is in $T,$ and (2) $G$ was chosen to be a model of $T$ (we know that such a $G$ exists because we proved that $T$ is satisfiable). But this means that the interpretation of $c$ in $G$ does not lie on a cycle. This contradicts the fact that every member of $G$ lies on a cycle, which we know because: (3) $\phi$ is in $T,$ (4) $G\models T,$ and, (5) by assumption, any graph that models $\phi$ has the property that for each node in the graph, there's some cycle that that node lies on.